# How to model multinomial output given one categorical input?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, biostatistics, methodology

I have climate and vegetation data by latitude longitude.
The vegetation data is a categorical variable with 20 possible options.
The climate data is relative frequency of occurrence (RFO) for a dozen climate states - adding up to 100%.

```
Lat, Lon, Veg, CS1, CS2, CS3, CS4, CS5, CS6, CS7, CS8, CS9, CS10, CS11, CS12,
39.5, 178.5, 2, 0, 0, 33, 17, 20, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 8,
39.5, 179.0, 1, 0, 0, 23, 20, 17, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 
...
```

[image: head and tail 10 of my data as an example]

What I want is a model where I can input the vegetation data classification and it gives a most likely RFO for each climate state. As this will then be applied to past fossil sites, I do not wish to use the longitude and latitude as input data.

Using Random Forest models I already know that the climate data can predict the vege classification ~80% of the time, with quite a lot of 'near-misses' according to the confusion matrix, but what I need is the flip-side of this - if I input the vege data, can I get the RFO of the climate states.

I have been looking at K-means clustering, Linear Discriminant Analysis and Multiple Nominal Logistic Regression, but I am unsure if these apply to what I am trying to achieve. I also thought about producing probability densities for each climate state for each vege type, but I am not sure if there is already a method that would do that in a more functional way, or perhaps a simpler way.

Are their existing statistical or machine learning techniques that achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Is it fair to say that the main problem you face is finding a model to predict proportions summing to 1?

Comment: I am not sure - I don't think I understand your meaning. 
I want to be able to say, if site X has vegetation type Y, climate state 1 RFO  = 0%, climate state 2 RFO  =33%, climate state 3 RFO  = 17% ....climate state 12 RFO  = 20%

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example of what your data look like. Is site a feature? Or is vegetation type the only feature? Are you trying to predict which RFO is the largest, or are you trying to predict each value of RFO?

Comment: To me this is still unclear---can you at least make your data example clearer, with appropriate layout and column headers?  AND, a more descriptive title! thye present title will not attract readers ...

Comment: @dipetkov
No, I do not wish longitude and latitude to be included. What I have now is the modern data distribution, but ultimately, I wish to use this data to make predictions about the climate states in the past based on the vegetation. In the past the distribution of climate by latitude and longitude will differ. 
I will try to add example data in a different way now, but I do not know how to improve the title. Perhaps that would require me to already have a better idea of the answer.

Comment: I see. But the distribution of climate wasn't all the same in time either. It depends on what you mean by "in the past". Anyway, predicting one categorical variable from compositional data is much easier than the reverse problem. One way to think about this: The most any method can do is to generate 20 distinct predictions, one for each level of the categorical variable. That's the maximum "resolution" you can get.

Comment: Yes, I know, but that is what I want.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to add the dput output as suggested in the reproducibility examples due to the character limit. I have inserted example data as an image.

Comment: I used

eg <- rbind(head(mydata, 10), tail(mydata, 10))

dput(eg, "/Users/../dataeg")

Then tried copying the dput file into a code block, but it displayed the dput file as is. I am not sure if I should have done something that would then format the dput output, or if that is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Much better. `dput` is not strictly necessary; I just think the Stack Overflow instructions are clearer on this point. I'm sorry if I made it more complex than necessary. You might also want to go over your comments and add any relevant information that's in a comment to the text of the question. Many users don't read comments.